# How to check Windows system directory contents via Nagios?

Tags: nagios

I've run into a request for a new Nagios monitor to ensure that a system is processing inbound records.  The system in question is a Windows box and I'm monitoring several other things there with check_nt.  The parameters that I have been given is to check a specific directory and alarm if there are more than 5 files in that directory which is indicative of the MSSQL stored procedure not pulling the files properly.

I have been having no luck finding a complete list of all the options available for check_nt.  For instance, I do check a specific log file on another Windows server for activity using the "FILEAGE" option for check_nt but I sure can't find any reference to that any longer and I'm honestly not sure how I found the syntax for that years ago when I initially setup that particular check.

Anyone have any ideas how to get a count of files in a specific directory using check_nt?

Comment: Does it have to use check_nt? There are plenty of custom plugins that do this like [this one] (http://serverfault.com/questions/192158/use-nagios-to-monitor-files-in-folders) or this [search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=nagios+count+files+in+folder&safe=active)

Comment: What is your client? Do you use NsClient? You can make a custom check with that fairly easy as well. Check [this](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/CheckDisk/CheckFiles) out.